# How to loose 7-10kg weight in a month

Tags: weight-loss

I am aiming to lose 7-10 kg in a month. But not sure how to go about it. From what I have read, I am planning to do the following

1. Walk 10 km
2. Play badminton for 30-45 mins
3. 45 mins strength + cardio
   May include cycling too if possible.
   Now comes the diet part. Probably I have to focus on eating healthy and fewer calories. 
   Any suggestions or thoughts on the above approach or some other ideas about it?

Comment: The linked question has a great answer that addresses yours too. If your question is inherently different, please elaborate on it.

Comment: Apart from weight loss, I am also asking about the workout schedule I have posted. It's a pretty intense one. Wanted to know if it's a good idea to go for it? People going for some military training would be doing a much more intense workout than the one mentioned. Is there any harm in it or any ways to improve it?

Comment: Given the extra time at hand. Should one indulge in more exercise, mainly bodyweight, as fewer chances of injury?

Comment: We can't tell you what's too much exercise for you. That differs from person to person. You're gonna have to try it and find out. For some, it's too much. For others, it's not enough. More importantly, diet has a larger effect on your weight than exercise, so the exercise is more of a secondary tool to lose weight.